# How can you select an Excel sheet in win32com?

Tags: python, excel, select, win32com

I'm trying to write a win32com script to select a sheet by number but am finding that the sheet select doesn't work.

1. **I've tried writing a script like this:**

   ```
   excel = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
   excel.Visible = 1
   source = excel.Workbooks.Open(filepath_generic_win32)
   source.Sheets(2).Select
   ```

but find that sheet 1 is still selected.

2. **I've also tried the ActiveSheet method e.g.:**

   ```
   xl.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate()
   ```

but to no avail.

Can someone please explain to me how I can select a sheet in win32com?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a project that goes in to Excel, displays sheet 1, completes a task, then moves to sheet 2, completes a task, moves to sheet 3 and so on. I have excel visible at the moment so I can see it switching sheets and running the task.

My code relevant to switching sheets is:

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("Workbook_name.xls")
wb.Worksheets("Sheet_name").Activate()
```

Hope this helps you, it certainly works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some ComboBox, for example:

```
# Code for PyQt6

my_combobox = QComboBox()

my_combobox.addItem('Sheet 1')
my_combobox.addItem('Sheet 2')
my_combobox.addItem('Sheet 3')

file_location = '.../my_file.xlsx'

app = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(file_location)

# Select the sheet exactly you want:
workbook.worksheets(my_combobox.currentText()).Activate()
```